# Flash CS4/AS3: trying to make part of a movieclip loop only while keyboard button is pressed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, flash-cs4, keyboard-events

I'm working on a project in which a character walks forwards or backwards across the screen or shoots a rifle depending on whether the user presses one of the following keyboard keys: forward arrow (key 39), back arrow (key 37) or spacebar (key 32).

My problem is that when the user presses and holds the forward arrow key, the character's movieclip plays one instance of the walking forward animation, and then moves forward. I want the walking forward animation to play throughout the entire time the character is moving.

Here is my code:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveCharacter);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, stopCharacter);

var muzzlePosition:Number = new Number();
var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet();

function moveCharacter(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 39 :
        if (sprite_Cicada.x<stage.stageWidth-150) {
            sprite_Cicada.gotoAndPlay("walk-fwd");
            sprite_Cicada.x+=5;
        } else {
            sprite_Cicada.x+=0;
            sprite_Cicada.gotoAndPlay("push");
        }
        break;

    case 37 :
        if (sprite_Cicada.x>225) {
            sprite_Cicada.x-=3;
            sprite_Cicada.gotoAndPlay("walk-bkwds");
        } else {
            sprite_Cicada.x-=0;
            sprite_Cicada.gotoAndPlay("standing");
        }
        break;

    case 32 :
        muzzlePosition=sprite_Cicada.x+sprite_Cicada.AK47.x+28;
        addChild(bullet);
        bullet.gotoAndStop("lead");
        bullet.x=muzzlePosition;
        bullet.y=328;
        sprite_Cicada.gotoAndPlay("fireAK");
        var shootBullet:Tween=new Tween(bullet,"x",None.easeOut,muzzlePosition,stage.stageWidth*2,.5,true);
        if (bullet.x>stage.stageWidth+50) {
            removeChild(bullet);
        }
        break;
    }
}

function stopCharacter(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
sprite_Cicada.gotoAndPlay("standing");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydown );
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyup);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePerson);
function keydown(e:KeyboardEvent) {
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) { per_mc.gotoAndStop(2) }
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {leftkeyStatus = true; rightkeyStatus = false;}
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {leftkeyStatus = false; rightkeyStatus = true;}
    }
function keyup(e:KeyboardEvent) { 
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) { per_mc.gotoAndStop(1) }
        if (e.keyCode == (Keyboard.LEFT)) {leftkeyStatus = false;}
        if (e.keyCode == (Keyboard.RIGHT)) {rightkeyStatus = false;}
    }

    function movePerson(e:Event) {
        if (rightkeyStatus) {
    sprite_Cicada.x-=3;
        }           
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code, but I kept getting the following error, multiple times, at several lines in my code: `1120: Access of undefined property leftkeyStatus.` and `1120: Access of undefined property rightkeyStatus.`